# Python Regular Expression : detecting the pattern which include specific word together?

Tags: python, regex

Sentence : `"[cnn news, Chris] Stackoverflow is awesome"`.

What I want to detect with regular expression is `[cnn news, Chris]` part.

What I tried: `re.search(r"[cnn news, \w+]", sentence)` but it only detected `c`(first letter)...

What's wrong with my expression?

Comment: Try `\[cnn news, \w+]` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY73e7/1)

Comment: You could try this `\[[^"]*\]`

Answer (score 0):

So – [Regex101](https://regex101.com) is a fantastic tool for building and debugging regular expressions.

In this instance, you probably want to use a capture group to get the text within the square brackets at the start of your string. The best way I can think of would be like this: `^\[(.*)\]`.

Regex101 explains this better than I can at this link: https://regex101.com/r/LfrbL2/1/

This regular expression basically looks for a `[` at the start of the input text, and then captures everything after that `[` until it hits a `]`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to extract the content inside brackets, in addition to searching for it.  We can use the pattern `\[([^\]]+)\]` with a capture group:

```
sentence = "[cnn news, Chris] Stackoverflow is awesome"
result = re.search("\[([^\]]+)\]", sentence)

if result:
    print "Found a match: ", result.group(1)
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to use your pattern [`[cnn news, \w+]`](https://regex101.com/r/J4LbTp/1) in a  [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match only one out of several characters.

If you want to match `[cnn news, Chris]`, you have to escape`\[` the opening square bracket:

[`\[cnn news, \w+]`](https://regex101.com/r/37b4bw/1)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YVKT3217)

To match your pattern inside square brackets `[]` starting with `cnn news,`  you could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=` to assert that what is on the left side is a `[`

Then match your pattern `cnn news, \w+` and at the end use a positive lookahead `(?=\])` to assert that what is on the right side is a `]`:

[`(?<=\[)cnn news, \w+(?=\])`](https://regex101.com/r/mWh2cz/1)

```
import re
sentence = "[cnn news, Chris] Stackoverflow is awesome";
result = re.search(r"(?<=\[)cnn news, \w+(?=\])", sentence)

if result:
    print result.group()
```

That will give you:

> cnn news, Chris

[Demo](http://rextester.com/UQFD90197)